# Bugs TabActivity in Child ActivityGroup

Tags: android, tabactivity, activitygroup

I created a TabActivity ...

and in the first tab, I call the class 'input'

I use ActivityGroup .. this example when I call the class 'input'

```
TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();

Intent intent = new Intent(getParent(), Input.class);

parentActivity.startChildActivity("Input", intent);
```

Within the child activity, I made ​​a edittext. This example image of what I mean ...

[image]

But when I enter text, and a virtual keyboard out ...

virtual keyboard does not appear above the tabs, but he pushed the tab above the virtual keyboard .. This example image is what I mean ...

[image]

see image above, tab above the virtual keyboard ..

This happens if I do it in the child activity group .. if I put edittext on the main tab. everything went smoothly ..

I need a solution about a problem that I can ...

Kind Regards,

Vootsugu

Answer (score 2):

I am also facing the similar issue.Thanks in advance.
I solved it via putting in AndroidManifest.xml, and add the following to your specific activity:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```