# When I open soft keyboard in child activity of activity group.Tabs shifted upward in Android

Tags: android, keyboard, tabs, activitygroup, childactivity

When I open soft keyboard in child activity of activity group.Tabs shifted upward

here is the images for the problem.
[Bugs TabActivity in Child ActivityGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321539/android-bugs-tabactivity-in-child-activitygroup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your AndroidManifest.xml, add the following to your specific activity:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it is not working for me,I already tried it.Please go through above link for more clarification of the problem.

Comment: Thank it is working I am doing the mistake sorry for you inconvenience.